# Unable to execute background task with limits

Tags: parse-platform

I'm trying to execute the following in cloud code:

```
  Parse.Cloud.job("fixUserStuffs", function(request, status) {

  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  query.limit(1000);
  query.each(function(user) {
      user.set('password', 'abc');
      return user.save();
  }).then(function() {

    status.success("completed successfully.");
  }, function(error) {

    status.error(error);
  });
```

but it's returning me the error 'Failed with: Cannot iterate on a query with sort, skip, or limit.' This seems kind of pointless to me since I either need to skip or increase the number of objects returned rather than the default 100.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Parse.Query.each()`, it will process **ALL** records.  1, 1000, 1000000.  It doesn't matter.

If you don't want to process all records, then you don't use `each`.